# How can I allow users to add an option to a dropdown list?

Tags: html

I have a dropdown list with many options. I want to create a button "Add option" so that the user can write a new option in a text input box, for example, and it would be automatically added to the list.

How can I do this?

Comment: You’ll want to have a look at JavaScript, especially [the `document.createElement` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `JavaScript` and may try something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9WZwF/1/))

**HTML:**

```
<select id="sel" name="sel">
    <option value='none'>None</option>
</select>
<input type='text' name='option' id='option' />
<button id='btnAdd'>Add Option</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btnAdd');
btn.onclick = function(){
    var tb = document.getElementById('option'), val = tb.value;
    if(val.length){
        var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = val;
        opt.innerHTML = val;
        sel.appendChild(opt);
        tb.value = '';
    }
};
```